# How do we convert jQuery prepend() to VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert jQuery:

```
$li = $(this);
$li.prepend('<span class="icon-"></span>');
```

function to VanillaJS using `createElement`.

```
li = document.createElement('span');
```

But still this statement does not do what `prepend` function does. Can you please suggest any better solution.

Comment: You can see how it's done in the jQuery source: https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.prepend - `insertBefore()`

Comment: http://callmenick.com/post/prepend-child-javascript

Comment: You can still use HTML for this instead of `createElement`. Use [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) like this.. `li.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<span class='icon-'></span>")`

Comment: @spanky since `$li` represent `$(this)` seems we can't use `insertAdjacentHTML` here. Got a 'TypeError' when do the execution. So any better option instead of using `insertAdjacentHTML` ?

Comment: So don't use jQuery. `this.insertAdjacentHTML(...)` Your question is asking for Vanilla JS so you just use the DOM element that `this` points to directly.

Comment: @spanky `this.insertAdjacentHTML(...)`not worked and got the following error msg `Uncaught TypeError: this.insertAdjacentHTML is not a function`. Seems need to replace `HTMLElement` instead of using `this`. Could you please let me know any better way to do this.

Comment: If `this` is an element, which it seems to be, it should work. Check for typos. Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5epmetrh/

Comment: Thank you @spanky. Yes it works perfect and did some changes in `this` element .

Comment: Very good. Glad it worked.